# Create symlink to /usr/local/lib/cmake from Homebrew Formula

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew, symlink

I wrote a custom Homebrew Formula to distribute some library. I'm happy with the result, but there's an outstanding problem. I would like to install the cmake config file (`YORPLibConfig.cmake`) in `/use/local/lib/cmake`.

Unfortunately, this location appears to be out of reach from within the Formula. I had no problems to install the library and its headers thanks to the nifty `lib.install` and `include.install` functions, but I'm out of luck since there's no `lib/cmake.install` equivalent.

I also tried to manually create the symlink by doing

```
ln_sf "YORPLibConfig.cmake", "/usr/local/lib/cmake/"
```

but the install fails upon throwing

```
Error: Operation not permitted @ rb_file_s_symlink - (YORPLibConfig.cmake, /usr/local/lib/cmake/YORPLibConfig.cmake)
```

How can I install this cmake file in `/usr/local/lib/cmake` from within the Formula?

The formula itself:

```
class Yorplib < Formula
  desc "A library for the computation of the Fourier decomposition of YORP forces and moments"
  homepage "https://github.com/bbercovici/YORPLib"
  url "https://github.com/bbercovici/YORPLib/archive/1.0.0.tar.gz"
  sha256 "45fb9a2969368e76e472a39afa8feb32c27cbe17032371e06fd283f3d70bb7c7"

  depends_on "cmake" => :build

  def install

    # Compile
    system "cmake . -DBREW:BOOL=TRUE && make"

    prefix.install "YORPLibConfig.cmake"

    # Create symlink to library
    ln_sf "YORPLibConfig.cmake", "/usr/local/lib/cmake/"

    lib.install "libYORPLib.dylib"
    include.install "include/"


  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up modifying both the formula and the CMakeLists.txt file so as to install a symlink to the configuration file in /usr/local/share. The configuration file pointed at by the symlink resides in the Cellar.